# NGINX automatically redirects subdomain to domain

Tags: nginx

So I know this seems like a question many people have asked before but I wasn't able to find an answer yet so I'll ask anyway.
I have a few websites set up on one IP address, which means I need to use SNI - one of said subdomains is mail.domain.tld, which works perfectly fine and another is cloud.domain.tld, which unfortunately doesn't.

1. cloud.domain.tld redirects to [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld) when it is up.
2. manually typing 'cloud.domain.tld/login' works even when other websites are up but I haven't been able to make the subdomain append /login automatically, which is what I want to do.
3. when I change the name of cloud.domain.tld to mail.domain.tld, leaving the entire config the same, it works.
4. when I added clou.domain.tld and clouds.domain.tld to my DNS settings and set the website to those it works too.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the location / block from
rewrite ^ /index.php$uri; - as default in owncloud configuration
to
return 301 /index.php$uri;
and now this problem has been resolved, however logging out now returns a CSRF error.